# transform latitude and longitude in unity position

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, geolocation

I'm using unity 5.3.1 with monoDevelop and C#, in windows 10.
I have 2 points in my scene, each of them have their latitude and longitude stored.

For one of this point I know also the unity position.

How Can I get the position for the second point?

for example:

- point1

LAT: 40.769554 and LON: 14.788634

unity X:5.6 Z:-19.17

- point2

LAT: 40.767949  LON: 14.790352

unity X:? z:?

I know about the Harvesine Formula, but this formula return a distance. There is a way to modify this formula to get what I want? or there is another way?

EDIT: more explanation

[map image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mmuN.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to enable anyone to answer that question.
Harvesine Formula returns the distance on great circles, meaning shortest distance on the surface of a sphere. Are you trying to find positions on a 3D sphere, or on a flat 2D projection of a sphere's surface?

Comment: Where is the center of your planet in Unity?

Comment: thanks for your replies
I added an image on my main post, I hope this can explain better my situation.